# Parse string by |

Tags: r

I have a list of strings which look like that:

`categories <- "|Music|Consumer Electronics|Mac|Software|"`

However, I only want get the first string. In this case `Music`(without `|`). I tried:

`sub(categories, pattern = " |", replacement = "")`

However, that does not give me the desired result. Any recommendation how to correctly parse my string?

I appreciate your answer!

**UPDATE**

```
> dput(head(df))
structure(list(data.founded_at = c("01.06.2012", "26.10.2012", 
"01.04.2011", "01.01.2012", "10.10.2011", "01.01.2007"), data.category_list = c("|Entertainment|Politics|Social Media|News|", 
"|Publishing|Education|", "|Electronics|Guides|Coffee|Restaurants|Music|iPhone|Apps|Mobile|iOS|E-Commerce|", 
"|Software|", "|Software|", "|Curated Web|")), .Names = c("data.founded_at", 
"data.category_list"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Several problems: 1) Your arguments for `sub` are in the wrong order. 2) You need to escape `|` with `pattern = "\\|"` 3) `sub` will only replace characters, not split strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative for this could be `scan`:

```
na.omit(scan(text = categories, sep = "|", what = "", na.strings = ""))[1]
# Read 6 items
# [1] "Music"
```

Answer (score 1):

Find a function that will tokenize a string at a particular character: `strsplit` would be my guess.

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strsplit.html

Answer (score 1):

Note that the parameter in split is a regexp, so using `split="|"` will not work (unless you specify fixed=TRUE, as suggested from joran -thanks- in the comments)

```
strsplit(categories,split="[|]")[[1]][2]
```

To apply this to the data frame you could do this:

```
sapply(df$data.category_list, function(x) strsplit(x,split="[|]")[[1]][2])
```

But this is faster (see the comments):

```
vapply(strsplit(df$data.category_list, "|", fixed = TRUE), `[`, character(1L), 2)
```

(thanks to Ananda Mahto)

Comment: And, if you use strsplit, which returns a list, you might want to call unlist on the expression @momobo provided.  That will return a vector.

Comment: @momobo Thx for your answer! How to do that on a dataframe?

Comment: @AnandaMahto I have added my used dataframe in an update. I would appreciate an answer from you, that I will gladly mark as accepted!

Comment: also df$firstCat <- sapply(df$data.category_list, function(x){strsplit(x,split="[|]")[[1]][2]})

Comment: Ok. Yours is faster. :)

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thx for your answer! Could you explain your function. I do not understand why you are having this: `, `[`, character(1L), 2)`?

Comment: (that´s why I preferred the slow one ;) ). Vivien, the [ is the function to access the list that strsplit provide. character(1L) is the prototype of the result (used to vapply for squeeze more speed out of the run). 2 is there as a parameter of [ as you want the 2th element of the list.